# Create a custom UIToolBarItem that exceeds UIToolBar height

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I would like to achieve something like the link below (middle bar).

I am wondering, is pure photoshop job, or you can set the middle item to has greater height (or width) from the actual toolbar?

http://www.mobilebricks.com/ios/altoolbar

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else out there, who is trying to achieve the same effect like me, please follow this [link](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar)

My mistake was that I was trying to customise a `UIToolBar` but with a `UITabBar` is easier.